# Create App Service Managed Certificates says success, but certificate does not appear

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, ssl-certificate, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to create  Service Managed Certificate for my web service in Azure. I have configured custom domain. Then went to the TSL/SSL tab here:
[image]

The operation ends and it says success, but certificate does not appear.
[image]

Did somebody face such issue? How to solve it?

Comment: I've definitely had some issues here where I expected the certificate to show up immediately after the success message became available, but it didn't. So far as I can tell, there are some backend replication issues between the certificate being created on the backend and it being made available for use.

Answer (score 2):

I was running into this same issue for the past hour. I ended up switching over to Edge (from Chrome) and tried switching regions for my plan, no luck.

Then I randomly got a "session expired" on the Azure portal, refreshed, and my private key appeared.

Comment: thank you, I did the same steps and it helped me as well. Maybe some issue at azure side. I am not sure where is the problem was. Today the cert for new web app issued without any problems :-(

Answer (score 1):

I encounded the same issues described in the question while using Chrome. Taking the lead from @n0madzer0 answer, I open the Azure Console in Edge instead of Chrome and then switched directory in the Azure Console.

[image: Azure Switch Directory]

Once I switched back again to the directory with the issue, the cert had magically appeared in the list!

Only half a day of my life wasted :(

Comment: the same steps worked for me as well. I also spent a lot of time :-( thank you for response!